# Question about Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Is a set $C = \{x \in R3 | x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 = 0 \}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$?

So far I have that $0 \in C : x1 = x2 = x3 = 0$, then you have 0*0 + 0*0 = 0, but

then I need to prove that the part where $U,V \in C : U + V \in C$?

I have that if $x=[1,0,0]$ and $y=[0,1,1]$, then $x+y=[1,1,1]$, and you'd have $1\cdot1 + 1\cdot1 = 2$, which does not $=0$, therefore $C$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Am I correct? If not, where am I wrong? Thanks!

Sorry for the poor formatting, I sent this from mobile.

Comment: You have the right idea, but the counterexample doesn't work, since  $y$ is not in $C$.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but the counterexample doesn't work, since  $y$ is not in $C$.  Instead, let $x=(0,1,0)$ and $y=(1,0,1)$.

Comment: How did you get those? Sorry, that part of the problem is the part I get stuck on

Comment: You can tell that if $x_2=0$, you get the equation satisfied.  Similarly, looking at the equation, if $x_1=x_3=0$, the equation is satisfied.

Comment: And that still leaves me with x+y=[1,1,1], right? Which means the rest of my answer is still correct, and that C is not a subspace of R3?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Great. Thank you for the clarification!